# Bind Multiple Selection List on Single call using MVC5 Ajax and Json

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

**This is my two ajax calls,i need to done it on single call.**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Job/GetJobType",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                        $("#DdlJobType").append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
                        $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
                            $("#DdlJobType").append($("<option></option>").val(value.TypeId).html(value.TypeName));
                        });
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Job/GetStatus",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                    if (typeof Result !== 'undefined' && Result != undefined) {
                        $("#DdlStatus").append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
                        $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
                            $("#DdlStatus").append($("<option></option>").val(value.StatusId).html(value.StatusName));
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Also i need to set selected value as in the database,
thanks**

Comment: You cannot make a single call to two different URLs, unless you combine them at action method.

Comment: how to combine it in action method ,i need code help

Comment: Basically, you create two enumerable properties inside a view model, and return the view model.

Comment: i am using Selection list instead of DropDownFor ,that's why i am using ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a single call to two different URLs. However, you can combine them at action method.

[image]

### View

```
<select id="DdlJobType"></select>
<select id="DdlStatus"></select>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Job/GetJobTypeAndStatus",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            $("#DdlJobType").append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
            $.each(response.JobTypes, function (key, value) {
                $("#DdlJobType").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Value).html(value.Text));
            });

            $("#DdlStatus").append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
            $.each(response.Status, function (key, value) {
                $("#DdlStatus").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Value).html(value.Text));
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

### Model

```
public class Model
{
    public List<SelectListItem> JobTypes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class JobController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetJobTypeAndStatus()
    {
        var model = new Model
        {
            JobTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Engineer", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Accountant", Value = "2"}
            },
            Status = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Active", Value = "true"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Inactive", Value = "false"}
            },
        };
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```